# How to identify and format numbers with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

My problem is occurs for some random reason most of the graphics library do not use the internalization of currencies so the values I am wanting to read and transfer to the graphs are already formatted using my local currency already tried in many ways to solve this and not I managed, however, to arrive at a possible and most probable solution it works this way:

```
1,00 | 1
10,00 | 10
500,00 | 500
5.000,00 | 5000
70.000,00 | 70000
900.000,00 | 900000
1.000.000,00 | 1000000
```

Especially when I set these values in strings I wanted to remove all semicolons and last two numbers in values below why if I just remove the commas the graph will only read as a value of 100 or 1000 for example:

```
1,00 => 1
10,00 => 10
```

And so on to any number that comes after comma must be removed and at the beginning only the points be removed...

A brief demonstration of how the result is on my chart:

http://jsfiddle.net/Qa2Tx/29/

If you know some way to format numbers of this work without touching the commas and dots of my local currency I will explode with joy but if you can only format as I mentioned above I will be extremely happy and thank you for two days I am trying to solve this :D

Comment: Simplest is use a library like http://numeraljs.com/

Comment: @charlietfl I've been taking a look at her and another numbro.js does it have this ability to always remove the last two numbers and all semicolons?

Comment: RTM? https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.allowDecimals

Comment: I'm sure you can configure to do what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a small demo of what you can do. You can use the `split()` function to split on the `,`. This will divide the value on to sides

> 10,00 => ['10','00']

And you can just target the first part afte the split

This is a demo for just one value

```js
var value = '1.000,00';

console.log(value.split(',')[0]);
```

This demo also remove the `.` and turns the value to a number

```js
var value = '1.000,00';

console.log(Number(value.split(',')[0].replace(/[^0-9]+/g,"")));
```

This demo represent an array of values

```js
var arr = ['1,00',
'10,00',
'500,00',
'5.000,00',
'70.000,00',
'900.000,00',
'1.000.000,00']

arr.map(value => console.log(Number(value.split(',')[0].replace(/[^0-9]+/g,""))))
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Doesn't return expected results

Comment: Why not? 10,00 => 10

Comment: `5.000,00` should result in 5000 not 5

Comment: Is perfect how can I remove the stitches too?

Comment: I parse the out put to remove the ``.`` and make it a number. When a value has a ``,`` it is a string. Using ``Number()`` or ``parseInt()`` you can turn that value into a number.

Comment: @charlietfl edited the answer. Any retro that can help?